# R: Generate Random Numbers with "floor" and "runif"

Tags: r, random, integer, range

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to generate random integers between 1 and 0. Using the following link (http://www.cookbook-r.com/Numbers/Generating_random_numbers/), I tried this code to generate 1000 random integers between 0 and 1:

```
x = floor(runif(1000, min=0, max=1))
y = floor(runif(1000, min=0, max=1))
group <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.8,0.2) )

d = data.frame(x,y,group)
d$group = as.factor(d$group)
```

However, both "x" and "y" seem to only have a value of 0.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `floor` round down your sample return to integer, so makes sense.

Comment: If you want to sample from a distribution of 0/1 values, use `rbinom`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?floor`

> floor takes a single numeric argument x and returns a numeric vector containing the largest integers not greater than the corresponding elements of x.

Let's look at an example to understand this -

```
floor(c(5.3, 9.9, 6.5, 1.2))
[1] 5 9 6 1
```

`floor` always rounds down to nearest integer. In your example, with `runif` you are generating numbers between 0 and 1 and since you are using `floor` all the numbers are rounded down to 0 hence you only get 0 as output.

Comment: Thank you Ronak Shah! Is there a easier way to directly generate random numbers between 1 and 0?

Comment: I always use `runif` as you already have. Do you face any issues with that?

Comment: I tried "x = runif(1000, min=0, max=1)" . This works, but it produces decimal numbers. I am trying to produce either 1 or 0. I could write an extra statement, ifelse x > 0.5, 1,0 ... but I am trying to find a more direct way. Do you have any ideas? thanks

Comment: I see. If you want random 0's and 1's use `sample` - `sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4):

To generate random *integer* numbers of `0` or `1` you can use `rbinom` or `sample`.

```
x <- rbinom(1000, 1, 0.5)
str(x)
# int [1:1000] 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 ...
```

```
x <- sample(0:1, 1000, TRUE)
str(x)
# int [1:1000] 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
```

In case you have only `0` and `1` maybe it would be better to use a *logical* vector allowing only `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

```
x <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1000, TRUE)
str(x)
# logi [1:1000] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
round(stats::runif(1000), digits = 0)
```

The default values of min and max are 0 and 1 in runif. `round()` rounds to the closest integer.

Answer (score 1):

Two other ways to generate two random integers using `runif` :

```
a <-  round(runif(1000000, min=-0.5000001, max=1.4999999), 0)
table(a)

b <-  floor(runif(1000000, min=0.00000001, max=1.9999999))
table(b)
```